# Celey + Python ignores update_state calls

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have a scenario where I need to update the state of a task to a custom value, then read it and apply some logic according to the value.

This is my celery configuration :

```
celery = Celery(app.import_name,
                backend='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0',
                broker='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0')
celery.conf.update(CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='pickle',
                   CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0',
                   CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=False,
                   CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=False,
                   CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['pickle'],
                   CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='pickle')
```

So I'm using redis + pickle basically. The calls to update the state are made like

```
self.update_state('foo')
```

but when I call my task like this and check the state:

```
result = task.delay(*args)
print(result.state)
```

I always get either `PENDING` or `SUCCESS`, so any intermediary values are skipped, even if the calls to update are definitely made

If I check the result backend type, I get Redis, and the `ignore_result` option is set to False, to none of the suggested fixes I found here work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at signature of `update_state` method, it looks like this

```
 def update_state(self, task_id=None, state=None, meta=None):
    """Update task state.

    :keyword task_id: Id of the task to update, defaults to the
                      id of the current task
    :keyword state: New state (:class:`str`).
    :keyword meta: State metadata (:class:`dict`).
```

When we run

```
self.update_state('foo')
```

it tries to update a task with task_id `foo` to state `None`.

Instead we should try

```
self.update_state(state='foo')
```

which updates current task status to `foo`.